# How many solutions are there to a given instance of the game *LYNE*?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

Recently I've been playing a nice little puzzle game called [LYNE](http://lynegame.com/), which involves building a (special) graph out of a given set of vertices and prescribed valencies, and I've been wondering what could be said about the solutions to one such problem. More formally:

**Definition 1**: Let's call an *L-set* any finite set of pairs $\mathbf{v} = (v,d)$ with $v\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $d\in\{1,2,4,6,8\}$ such that each $v$ appears only once and the number of pairs with $d=1$ is even.

**Definition 2:** Let's call an *L-graph* any (finite) plane graph $G$ such that:

1. The valency of any vertex is $1,2,4,6$, or $8$.
2. The number of vertices with valency $1$ is even.
3. The edges have length at most $\sqrt{2}$.
4. The set of edges of $G$ can be partitioned in such a way that each subset can be ordered into a path(possibly with loops, but with no repetitions) from one vertex of valency $1$ to another.

**Definition 3:** Consider an L-set $\mathcal{V}$ and let
$$
V = \left\{v\in\mathbb{Z}^2 : (v,d)\in\mathcal{V} \text{ for some } 
d\in\{1,2,4,6,8\} \right\}
$$
Then a *solution* to the *L-problem* posed by $\mathcal{V}$ is a set of edges $E$ such that $(V,E)$ is an L-graph and each $v\in V$ has valency $d$, where $(v,d)\in\mathcal{V}$.

---

**I would like to answer the following (possibly hard) questions:**

- Given an L-set, are there any criteria to decide if the corresponding L-problem admits a solution, other than brute force? (bonus points for an effective way of computing the number of solutions)

*Edit:* As pointed out by wonce, it looks like finding a solution to a special L-problem is [NP-complete](http://jeffreybosboom.com/blog/articles/review-and-analysis-lyne/). It is unclear (at least to me) if this is the general case: there may be some sizable subclasses of L-problems for which finding solutions is simpler.

- Can we find a reasonable bound on the number of solutions to an L-problem?

**Note 1:** By *reasonable* I mean any bound remotely useful. Clearly the number of solutions to the L-problem given by $\mathcal{V}$ is bounded by the number of planar graphs on $|\mathcal{V}|$ vertices each with valency at most $8$, but you can guess why I'm not happy with this piece of information.

**Note 2:** If such a bound exists, I would expect it to depend on the cardinalities of the sets $\mathcal{V}$ and $\{(v,d)\in\mathcal{V} : d=i\}$ for each $i\in\{1,2,4,6,8\}$.

Comment: Please note that I glimpsed my little knowledge of graph theory mostly from Wikipedia, so any references relevant to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think you have completely modeled the game LYNE. For example the L-set {((0,0), 2), ((0,1), 1), ((0,2), 1), ((0,3), 2)} would admit an L-graph but poses an insolvable LYNE-puzzle since you may not draw an edge connecting the two outermost vertices.
You might want to limit your vertices to points in Z^2 and require edges to be of maximum length sqrt(2).

Comment: According to http://jeffreybosboom.com/blog/articles/review-and-analysis-lyne/ finding a solution is NP-complete.

Comment: I incorporated your objection. I was thinking about define two problems $P$ and $Q$ as equivalent if they both admit solution and the solutions are isomorphic (as graphs), but then it is unclear if every solution has to $P$ has to be isomorphic to a solution to $Q$; I resisted the urge to define equivalence as "every solution to $P$ is isomorphic to a solution of $Q$", as this seemed to be rather unwieldy. In either case, your example would be equivalent to an L-set which poses a valid LYNE-puzzle.